# Why are most solar panel rated at 12 volts or 24 volts?

Tags: voltage, conventions, electronics, electrical-engineering, solar-cells

Most solar panel come in 12 volts or 24 volts, why?

Comment: Consider the voltage of car & truck batteries.

Comment: This is solely because most people and engineers are working with 12V or 24V systems with car batteries.  My previous company made solar powered crosswalk lights. We used 4V solar panels and 4V batteries because most electronic circuitry runs at 3.5V and having the voltage this close provided the most efficient system at gathering and using solar power.  This also allowed us to gather solar power on overcast days.